# How do I change the location of macOS screen captures?

Tags: macos, screen-capture, defaults, path

As a developer, I take a lot of screen captures. I often take screen shots to share with Stack Exchange members in chat.

The problem is my Desktop is so cluttered with screen captures that they're now overlapping! I'd like to save all screenshots in a dedicated folder or directory.

In macOS, how do I change the default location where screen captures are saved?

These are the screen shots taken with <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> keyboard shortcuts.

I would prefer a solution which doesn't require installing any software.

Comment: There are some subtleties with Touch Bar that add options, but the core functionality of a default folder is something you can set on each version of macOS with specific actions. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263424/ may be the main Touch Bar version of this

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to [this page](http://snowleopardtips.net/tips/everything-you-need-to-know-about-screen-captures.html)...

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location <path>
```

Also, to turn on/off shadow:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool true
defaults write com.apple.screencapture disable-shadow -bool false
```

And to change file type:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type <format>
```

You'll want to

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

to make the commands take effect.

Answer (score 9):

As of macOS 10.14+, you don't need any specific software or scripts. The default screenshot location can be changed in the Screenshot app UI:

1. Enter Screenshot mode:

   - Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
   - Press the Touchbar's Screenshot button
2. Go to the floating screenshots options window.
3. Select `Options > Save to > Other Location...`
4. Choose a new screenshot location.

---

Select "Options" here:

[image: Screenshot options]

Now all screenshots will be stored at the chosen location.

Comment: This is my vastly-preferred answer for modern macOS-es.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) you can change the location that screen capture will saved:

[image]

And also you can Add <kbd>control</kbd> to the two shortcuts above to place the screen shot on the clipboard instead of saving it to the desktop., and paste it in image Editor like Acorn.

Comment: Thanks... any way to do it using `defaults` ?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question was asked years ago...

Nonetheless, I arrived here yesterday trying to fix the *names* (base filenames) of the screencapture PNG files.

Later I found the answer I needed, so I offer it here for future visitors.

If you hate the names looking like:

```
Screen shot 2011-07-05 at 5.38.53 AM
```

Then you can fix it in three steps:

First, run:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture name "screenshot"
```

Or use any word you want as a replacement for the default "Screen shot."

Then (bust out your superuser/sudo privileges and) edit this file:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Localizable.strings
```

If your computer is not localized to use the "English.lproj", then locate the appropriate lproj in that same Resources folder.

Here is what to edit in Localizable.strings:

```
/* Format screencapture file names */
/* "%@ %@ at %@" = "%1$@ %2$@ at %3$@"; */
"%@ %@ at %@" = "%1$@_%2$@_%3$@";
```

Keep the left-hand-side as "%@ %@ at %@" and alter the right-hand-side  (after the equals sign) to your liking.  In the above snippet, underscores are used where previously whitespace was used.

Lastly, of course:

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

I found this info [on this webpage](http://zoomq.qiniudn.com/ZQScrapBook/ZqFLOSS/data/20130328152918/index.html), and it works for me on 10.6.

Comment: This is great info, but should be asked as a new question (How can I change the *name* of a screen capture file) and then copy your answer to that. It's perfectly Ok (and encouraged!) to ask and answer your own question in order to share knowledge. Post a comment on my question with a link to your question after you post it and I'll upvote you.

Comment: @Josh - thanks! actually, you should probably just upvote Lri here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53422/save-screenshot-with-my-own-name#53470  ... I found Lri's answer *after* all this mess. The thing is: your question consistently showed up in google searches, and that other one *never* did (but i eventually found it just browsing stackexchange without google).

Comment: Note that this will not work on 10.11+ as anything in `/System/` is protected by System Integrity Protection (SIP).

Answer (score 0):

Apple's answer:

> ## Where to find screenshots
>
> By default, screenshots save to your desktop with the name ”Screen Shot [date] at [time].png.”
>
> In macOS Mojave or later, you can **change the default location of saved screenshots from the Options menu in the Screenshot app**. You can also drag the thumbnail to a folder or document.
>
> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361

Comment: Does that have the same effect as using the `defaults` command I have enjoyed for 10 years?

Comment: @Josh I think [gyunter's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/347773/19829) is now the best on this page and should be chosen as the Accepted Answer. It's now easy to do via the Screenshots UI.

Answer (score -2):

Use the screen shots from Preview. You can save to any place you like, change the screenshot's name or file type. It is under Previews File menu.

Comment: You've misunderstood my question. Obviously I can *move* them after they're taking, I wanted to know how to change their location when they're taken.