# Is it possible to change the file format of Grab.app?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I know that you can change the format used by <kbd>⌘⇧3</kbd> and <kbd>⌘⇧4</kbd> ([SE answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-screen-captures-on-10-5/4143#4143) and [external source](http://snowleopardtips.net/tips/everything-you-need-to-know-about-screen-captures.html)), but is it also possible to change the format of [Grab.app](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/apps-and-utilities.html#grab) (uses TIFF)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible. Even the limited Help for Grab.app suggests using Preview to convert away from TIFF. I presume you need "Timed Screen Captures" otherwise you would use the keyboard shortcuts?

Note that you can take the grab, then copy the image without saving (CMD+A, CMD+C), then ALT+TAB to Preview.app, then CMD+N, then save. Not very elegant.

You could also just deal with Grab.app saving as TIFF, but then set up an Automator action that watches a folder and converts TIFF to whatever you want each time a TIFF shows up in the folder. This ought to be fairly easy and transparent way to use Grab.app and get the file formats of your choice.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a great tast for Automator. It has the same end result, and is probably the easiest solution without hacking about. Weird that they don't support other formats though.

Comment: It seems like I will have to do some Automator work for this. That's not very Apple like, three different solutions (Grab, Preview and ⌘⇧4) that don't share the same backend...

Answer (score 0):

No you can't change it from TIFF

Grap help gives

> Converting Grab screen shots to other formats
>   Grab saves screen shots as files in TIFF format. If you want to use your screen shots on the web, in email, or in a word processor, you can use the Preview application to convert the TIFF files to other formats, such as JPEG or PNG.
>
> To convert a Grab screen shot to
>   another format:
>
> Open Preview, located in Applications.
>
> Open Preview Choose File > Open and
>   choose the file to convert.
>
> Choose File > Save As and choose a
>   file format from the Format pop-up
>   menu.
>
> You can also use applications from
>   other manufacturers to open and
>   convert TIFF files created in Grab.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason not to use the screen capture functionality built in to Preview?  This way you can save as any format immediately, instead of having to use Preview (or sips, or whatever) to convert after the fact.

Comment: Delay timed shots aren't supported by Preview.app

Comment: Bummer.  I don't have a great answer to your original question then other than something like SnapzPro.