# Change the directory used to save screenshots

Tags: snow-leopard, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the location of screen captures on 10.5?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-screen-captures-on-10-5)

In the Keyboard preferences, I enabled the shortcuts that allow me to take a screenshot of the full screen, or of the part I select.

Is there a way to select in which directory will the file be saved?

Comment: Also a dup of http://superuser.com/questions/35334/how-do-i-change-the-default-screenshot-location-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) to change your "Screenshot file format" and "Target Folder for Screenshot"

[image]