# Save screenshot with custom name

Tags: screen-capture

When I save a screenshot I want to be able to specify any name I want (and maybe destination directory). Sharpshooter for mac does this, but it's a ridiculous $15. Cheaper alternatives?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Changing the prefix part of the names

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture name "My Screenshot"
killall SystemUIServer
```

#### Changing the format of the names

**UPDATE**: by 2021, the location of `ScreenCapture.strings` has moved from `English.lproj` (older macOS) to `en.lproj` (today's macOS).

```
f=/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/ScreenCapture.strings
f2=~/Desktop/ScreenCapture.strings
sudo cp $f $f2
sudo chown $USER $f2
plutil -convert xml1 $f2
open $f2 -a TextEdit
```

Change

```
<key>%@ %@ at %@</key>
<string>%@ %@ at %@</string>
```

To something like

```
<key>%@ %@ at %@</key>
<string>My %@ %@ at %@</string>
```

(The default format is currently something like `Screen Shot 2012-06-12 at 8.02.40 AM` depending on the locale settings.)

```
sudo chown root $f2
sudo cp $f2 $f
killall SystemUIServer
```

#### Changing the default location

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Pictures/
killall SystemUIServer
```

#### Using custom scripts

I've disabled the default shortcuts and have [assigned shortcuts to scripts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28272/3936) like `` screencapture -i ~/Desktop/`date '+%y%m%d%H%M%S'`.png ``.

Comment: I would never ever ever recommend editing a file in /System/. You can change the prefix of new screen captures via defaults, e.g. `defaults write com.apple.screencapture name "Foo Bar"` and then `killall SystemUIServer` You will still get the date/time information at the end of the filename, but I think that's a feature. You've provided a great answer. It was just that one part that was dubious, IMO.

Comment: "depending on the locale settings" -- this is useful for people who are looking to get 24-hour time strings into their screenshots so they sort properly on your desktop! Change your date and time settings in system preferences to do this.

Comment: I tried setting my screen capture location to a remote filesystem which is not always connected. Initially it worked. Then when I disconnected the filesystem it started using the desktop. When I reconnect to the filesystem, I need to do `killall SystemUIServer` again otherwise it keeps using the desktop.

Comment: I was not able to find `<key>%@ %@ at %@</key>` in the `ScreenCapture.strings` file with today's macOS, should I add this lines instead? And during `sudo cp $f2 $f` I am getting following error `cp: cannot create regular : Operation not permitted` . PS: sorry for commenting on 10 year old answer

Answer (score 2):

[Skitch](http://www.skitch.com/) lets you do this, as well as online sharing, annotation, and drawing, and it's free.

Comment: Skitch is the cheapest and easiest solution, by far. If you don't already have it, I highly recommend that you take a look at it.

Comment: Can we run Skitch offline?

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way than [Laurie's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/53470/7833) is to use a free application called [Deeper](http://www.titanium.free.fr/). It is *really* easy to use. Just enter in the name of that you want in the screenshot name field (under the General tab):

[image]

Click "Apply" and you are done. A nice feature of Deeper is the ability to restore all the default settings. If you've made a change to the settings that is causing your system to act up, no problem! At the bottom of each tab is a button that says "Restore Defaults". Deeper will fix up all your settings. I highly recommend this app, as it is free and adds a great deal of customization that OS X doesn't provide.

Comment: Is there a specific format to follow for the "Name:" field?

Answer (score 0):

[LittleSnapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/) does this and more. It's $40, but worth every penny.

Comment: It's also frequently available as part of Mac software 'bundles' where you can get 10 apps for $50, so keep an eyes out for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net/) to open a window like the following after taking a screenshot:

[image]

where you can edit/annotate your screenshot and then save it with whatever name you like, or save it to the cloud.

It's a pay-what-you-want model (minimum $3).  Best purchase I've ever made (for screenshot-ability and for many other reasons).