# Is there a way to change the naming scheme for screenshots?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save screenshot with my own name](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53422/save-screenshot-with-my-own-name)

Is there any way, short of a third-party application (I'm quite fond of the baked-in functionality of the screenshot system in Mac OS), to change the filename that screenshots get named with when they're created?

Failing that, are there any notable screenshot apps that give you better granular control over your screenshots, without nuking the process too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the Terminal, [screencapture](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html) lets you specify the name of the file (and much more).

Comment: Great! I don't suppose you have any links to where I can find syntax for that particular command?

Comment: @TerranceShaw, I'ved added a link to its man page. But you always do `man screencapture`.

Comment: There is an example of wrapping `screenshot` to get custom names in this duplicate Q&A: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53422/save-screenshot-with-my-own-name

Comment: Ah, so it is. Odd that it didn't show up when I searched for the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the "date at time" portion, but you can change the "Screen Shot" part preceding it.

Open Terminal and run `defaults write com.apple.screencapture name NAME_HERE` (replacing `NAME_HERE` of course). Then run `killall SystemUIServer`.

If you want to change the whole format, then you'll either need a 3rd party utility, or you could come up with a script and folder action to rename the files immediately as they're created.

Comment: actually, you can remove the date-and-time, but it is not for the faint of heart. You edit the ".strings" resource like mentioned here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53422/save-screenshot-with-my-own-name#53470 , but use "%@ %@ at %@" = "%1$@";