# How can I save screen shot name replacing white space with `_`?

Tags: screen-capture

When I save a screenshot, the  current filename shown as follows: `Screen Shot 2017-03-01 at 10.05.05.png`.  Instead of using a whitespace character, can we change it to another character like `_`?

Example filename: `Screen_Shot_2017-03-01_at_10.05.05.png`

Please note that on the latest macOS there is no `<key>%@ %@ at %@</key> <string>%@ %@ at %@</string>` in the `ScreenCapture.strings` file.

Related: [Save screenshot with custom name](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53422/save-screenshot-with-custom-name)

Comment: Why exactly was this downvoted?

Comment: Before I go to the trouble of writing an answer, I need to know if you're OK with an answer that uses a **shell script** (i.e not a GUI) to change the filenames that Apple automatically assigns. This would involve using `Terminal.app`  :-0

Comment: @Seamus Yes sir I am 100% OK with a shell script :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### A `zsh` script:

This script is a minimal solution to renaming all of the screenshots in a directory to replace every **space** with an underscore (**_**).

```shell
#!/bin/zsh
# shotfnmv.sh                  # FILE NAME FOR THIS SCRIPT
cd $HOME/Desktop/screenshots2  # CHOOSE YOUR FOLDER
for afile in *.png             # CHOOSE YOUR FORMAT; IF NOT .png
do
    if [[ $afile == "Screenshot "* || $afile == "Screen Shot "* ]]; then
      newfilenm=$(echo $afile | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/_/g')
      mv $afile $newfilenm
    fi
done
```

I've chosen to use the native (Apple) [`sed` (*stream editor*)](https://ss64.com/osx/sed.html) utility to perform the substitution; every space `[[:blank:]]` will be replaced by a single underscore `_`; the result is stored in the variable `newfilenm`. The filename (`afile`) will be re-named (using `mv`) to `newfilenm`, and so the original file name will be gone after this script is run.

Only those files that match one of the two criteria will be renamed, so if you keep files with "custom names" in the same folder, this script shouldn't rename them. I used two criteria (`"Screenshot "*` or `"Screen Shot "*`) for this screen because I know that on Ventura the single-word `Screenshot` is used instead of the dual-word `Screen Shot` as it is on your system.

##### A logistical issue:

Note that this solution leaves you with a logistical issue to resolve: ***How do I run this script when it needs to be run??***

I didn't address that issue here because you didn't specifically ask about it, but I'll outline a couple of approaches. You may choose to ask another question after reviewing the alternatives.

- **Use the `watch` command**

`watch` is a Linux/Unix utility that can detect when a file in a designated directory is added or changed, and this can be used to trigger another action (e.g. running the script above). It's not available natively in macOS, but you can get it through either of the commonly-used 3rd-party Package Managers: MacPorts or HomeBrew.

- **Set up a "User Agent" to run under `launchd`**

I use a 3rd-party app called `LaunchControl` for this sort of thing, but you can also use the native `launchctl` if you lean toward masochism :)  `LaunchControl` provides a *`watch`-like* feature which makes this very easy to do. `LaunchControl` isn't free, but it's not very expensive & well worth it IMHO.

- **Run the script continuously with `sleep`**

I don't like the idea of this - it just strikes me a wasteful and inefficient, but it's quite easy. There's a [thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574089/os-x-bash-watch-command) that discusses how to do this with some comparisons to `watch`. Closely related is using the `cron` utility to schedule times to run the script.

**EDIT:**

- **Automator perhaps?**

I've just noted a [new answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458938/149366) that may provide a more complete answer... Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Automator, but it may be just the ticket?

Comment: I appreciate how you explain everything from basics. When rename occurs does it affect the creation time of the file?

Comment: @alper: No - in my experiment, it did not change either the `Date Created`, nor the `Date Modified`. The `Date Added` did change, but this was due to copying the files from my original screenshot folder to my test folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution that you may be interested in. Using **Automator**, you can create a **Folder Action** that will rename files added to the specified folder, whose names contain blank spaces, with underscores.

First, open **Automator.app** and create a new **Folder Action**.  Then add a ***Run Shell Script*** command to the workflow and insert the following code.  The following image should show you what to do.

`for f in "$@" ;do echo "$f" |mv "$f" "$(sed 's@ @_@g')" ;done`

[image]

Then just save and name your new **Folder Action**.

After that, all you need to do is just open the **Folder Action Setup.app** and attach your new Folder Action to the target folder.

[image]

*The only issue is that with the above method, every single file added to that folder will be renamed if there are spaces in the file names... Not just the screenshot files.*

---

Now here is a little bit of a different solution if you were to already have a folder with a bunch of files, including the screenshot files with spaces in their names, and you only want to rename those screenshot files with spaces in their names while leaving everything else untouched… You can paste and run this following code into **Script Editor.app**, which will ask you to choose a folder and then it will rename those screenshot files with spaces in their names, within that folder.

```
activate
set chosenFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of (choose folder)

try
    do shell script "cd " & chosenFolder & ¬
        " ;for f in Screen* ; do echo \"$f\" |mv \"$f\" \"$(sed 's@ @_@g')\" ;done "
end try
```