# Change location of screenshots mac

Tags: terminal, folders, screen-capture, macos

Right now they default to desktop, and I followed instructions found [here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/06/15/how-to-change-where-screenshots-are-saved-on-mac/). It works up until I shut down the computer; I was wondering if there was a permanent solution?

Comment: I use [Tinker Tool](https://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/download.php) to change the screenshot location to a folder called "Screenshots" inside the Pictures folder. It's free. It only works with macOS Sierra.

Comment: What location did you change it to?

Comment: Run the Terminal command as a startup item.

Comment: Any `defaults write` command should be permanent, whether done from Terminal, Tinker Tool, Onyx etc they all actually implement the same command. Try this in Terminal `defaults read com.apple.screencapture location` before & after a reboot & let us know the result[s].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the location of macOS screen captures?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-macos-screen-captures)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Terminal command to change screenshot save location:

```sh
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location "/path/to/new/location"
```

**Put your desired screenshot path between the double quotes as it is required if any spaces exist in the location path!** Locations without a space will still be executed properly.

Example path with a space in new path:

```sh
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location "/Users/YourUserHomeFolder/Pictures/Screen Shots"
```

So no one is confused, the `~` character is a shortcut character symbol for your user's home folder. Other answers/sites might use this symbol.

Example:

```sh
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location "~/Pictures/Screen Shots"
```

The above `defaults` command will change the location screenshots are saved. The only problem is the path location must always be available or else it'll default back to the Desktop.

Example scenario: If you set the path to a removable volume such as a flash drive at `/Volume/USBFlashDrive` and remove it, or the location for some reason becomes unavailable from perhaps deleting, it'll revert back to its default location.

The only thing you'll need to change is the `/path/to/new/location`. This can be found from Finder by right clicking on your chosen folder. Then, after the context menu appears, hold the option key to change **Copy "..."** to **Copy "..." as Pathname**, so you can paste it into Terminal as the replacement for the example path provided above.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you should make new folder somewhere on your Mac. for example: `Screenshots` folder on `Desktop`.
2. Open the Terminal application on your Mac. Copy and paste this command to the Terminal window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop/screenshots/
   ```

   (However, If you wish to save screenshots in downloads folder the path looks this way: `~/Downloads/screenshots`)
3. Then paste this command to save changes and Press enter see immediate effect.

   ```
   killall SystemUIServer
   ```
4. Now use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> (eventually <kbd>4</kbd>) shortcut, you will see your screenshots are saved in your new location.

Answer (score -1):

Found [this tutorial](https://usefulpcguide.com/16910/change-default-screenshots-location-mac/) from Google.com

By that, just create a new folder somewhere else where you want to store screenshot. For example, Desktop -> Screenshots

Then perform this command in Terminal.

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/username/Desktop/Screenshots
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from the previous accepted one?