# Dropbox-like screenshot saving for Google Drive with URL copied to clipboard

Tags: macos, screen-capture, google-apps

One of the features I really like about Dropbox is the ability to have screenshots automatically saved to Dropbox *and* the sharing URL copied to your clipboard.

Is there any way to do this with Google Drive for Mac?

I'm not looking to simply change the location of screenshots, but also copy the sharing URL to my clipboard so I can easily share it in other apps (like Slack).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change location of screenshots mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258337/change-location-of-screenshots-mac)

Comment: Have you searched Google's support site for Drive on the Mac?  Let us know what you've already done yourself to answer your question so we don't suggest things you've already tried or read.  See [ask] for tips on asking questions.

Comment: Looks like a few other people asking the same question, there is a script available to automatically copy screenshots to a folder, or as Allan put you could change the directory.

Comment: You could then write a script to grab the share URL and use pbcopy to put it into the clipboard.

Comment: @Allan I did already search the docs and this form. I know how to change the default location for writing, but I would like to save it to Google Drive *and* save the sharing URL to my clipboard. Like how Dropbox does it, you just take the screenshot and click paste and the URL of the screenshot is publicly made.