# Shortcut to take screenshot and save to specific folder

Tags: macos, keyboard, screen-capture

Is there any way I can get a specific keyboard shortcut to take a screenshot and save it to a particular folder ?

The use case is quite simple: I listen to radio frequently and take screenshots of the songs I like. The screenshots go to my Desktop though. I would like to use a different shortcut than `cmd + Maj + 4` so that when triggered the screenshots default to another folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With native macOS You can **only** change the default save location for **all** screenshots to one location. The screenshot commands can't be split to have some screenshot commands go to one location, whilst other commands go to another location.

If your Mac is running Mojave or later, you can easily change the default screenshot location in the Options menu in the Screenshot app.

More information about Screenshots and the Screenshot app can be found at this [Apple Support document](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/take-a-screenshot-or-screen-recording-mh26782/11.0/mac/11.0). It is possible to customize the default macOS Shortcuts to key sequences you want to use, but you can't associate individual keystrokes with different save locations.

Comment: It could potentially be done with `defaults write` & bundled into a Service, but I'm not sure how much the SystemUIServer would appreciate being killed twice for every snap. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-macos-screen-captures